# Dry/cure time latex paint + concrete

Tags: concrete

Hoping you can help me out here, I mixed latex paint with Portland cement and 24 hours later they're sorta spongy. Definitely softer than I was expecting. Any idea what dry/cure time is gonna look like? These are pretty thick, 2 1/2-3"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Why did you do this? What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: `they're sorta spongy` ... what is "they" ?    .... downvote for incomplete information

Comment: @jsotola "they" is the mixture, apparently it's an effort to tint concrete.

Comment: @Harper, you are only guessing ... you never know what people will try to do

Comment: @jsotola read the first sentence again starting after the comma.

Comment: @Harper, I read it ... it mentions cement ... the OP made no mention of gravel and sand  .... the title mentions concrete, but I have no idea if the mixture is paint and cement or it it is paint and concrete